# ::1 vs 127.0.0.1 for iis local sites

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webserver, ipv6, iis

I have a local site which is running at admin.mysite.com. I have set up the iis config to point to the correct folder.

When i enter the following entry in my hosts folder

`127.0.0.1 admin.mysite.com`

it doesnt work. However, if i enter

`::1 admin.mysite.com`

it works fine, however `Chrome` wont permit this unless i specifically enable IPv6 (which dissapears after i restart the browser). Why isn't the default (`127.0.0.1`) working?

**Edit**

Site is bound to All Available IPs, on port 80.
OS is Windows 7

Comment: What do you mean by "Chrome won't permit this"? Chrome has no problems with IPv6 that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you go to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and set Enable IPv6, then when you restart the browser, it is disabled again. If i set this setting, it works, if i dont, it doesnt.

Comment: Did you bind the site to a IPv4 address?

Comment: What OS are you running? Does simply using the ip address on its own work?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, How do you bind specifically to an ipv4 address?

Comment: Pick one with no colons in it (other than a possibly optional port), such as `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams,

Should i be binding to a specific IPv4 address? I am not a guru with setting up IIS

Comment: My point was that [I don't see any such setting at all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3K6ER.png). Yet I have no difficulty accessing IPv6 sites, including `::1`.